# powershell date from keyboard

Tags: date, powershell, formatting, numbers

I have a script that renames files to dates entered by the user at the keyboard- It's very simple, just asks for the month, day, and year. As long as the user enters 2-digit values, it works well... the problem is that sometimes the user does not enter the leading 0, and then the whole thing falls apart. How do I make sure the leading 0 is included?
So far, here is what I have:

```
    $BatchDay = $(read-host "Enter Day of Month")
    if ($BatchDay -eq ''){$BatchDay = Get-Date -format dd}
    $BatchMonth = $(read-host "Enter Month of Year")
    if ($BatchMonth -eq ''){$BatchMonth = Get-Date -format MM}
    $BatchYear = $(read-host "Enter Year")
    if ($BatchYear -eq ''){$BatchYear = Get-Date -format yy}
```

Then it concatenates the numbers to build the filename:

```
    $Filename = "Customer--$BatchMonth-$BatchDay-$BatchYear($BatchNum).txt"
```

How do I force the variables to be two-digit, even when days and months are only one digit?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just create your filename formating your vars :

```
$a = ("{0:00}-{1:00}" -f 1,2)
```

gives

```
01-02
```

in your case :

```
$Filename = ("Customer--{0:00}-{1:00}-{2:00}({3:00}).txt" -f $BatchMonth,$BatchDay,$BatchYear,$BatchNum)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$Filename = 'Customer--{0:00}-{1:00}-{2:00}({3}).txt' -f $BatchMonth, $BatchDay, $BatchYear, $BatchNum
```

Comment: I'm revisiting this issue- Now I need more than just a filename variable, because the date is used in another function. What happens is the date becomes part of a find-replace that fails for the first 9 days of the month because the users enter the date as a single digit day... I appreciate your help!

Comment: So use the same formatting trick. Something like: $dateEntered = '{0:00}' -f (Read-Host 'Enter date')